# sed substitution works on command line but not in sed script ;(

Tags: regex, bash, sed, cygwin

I am trying to use a regex to upcase an attribute in an xml file.
The attr is item_id=
The line I am trying to parse out looks like this:

```
<Item acl_bits="0" active_seq="1" archive_date="" archive_info="" backup_date="" bom_view_tags="" configuration_object_tag="" creation_date="2007-09-12T20:28:24Z" date_released="" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id5017" fnd0InProcess="N" fnd0OriginalLocationCode="" fnd0RevisionId="" fnd0is_monolithic="" global_alt_list="" gov_classification="" has_variant_module="N" ip_classification="" is_configuration_item="N" is_vi="N" island_id="3517" item_id="SAN12542" last_mod_date="2007-09-12T20:30:59Z" last_mod_user="#id32" license_list="" lsd="" object_application="Teamcenter Engineering" object_desc="" object_name="C-rear_shell_intercostal_cutter" object_properties="0" object_type="Part-Ideas" owning_group="#id120" owning_organization="" owning_project="" owning_user="#id32" parent_uid="" pid="81" preferred_global_alt="" process_stage_list="" project_list="#id86" puid="2vHAAAxoxieWWC" release_status_list="" revision_limit="1" revision_number="0" timestamp="qSLAAAlkxieWWC" uom_tag="" wso_thread=""/>
```

Yep, I know lotsa junk here...
but at any rate the sed command I am using looks like this:

> /item_id/s/item_id=(\w*)/item_id=\U\1/g

now, this seems to work fine if I do something like in a cygwin windows shell:

```
 echo is_configuration_item="N" is_vi="N" island_id="3281" item_id="AP2i4i_77" last_mod_date="2007-09-11T18:13:39Z" | sed -e  's/item_id=\(\w*\)/item_id=\"\U\1\"/g'
```

The result is:

> blah blah  item_id="AP2I4I_77"  blah blah

However if I try this on MacOS the string is not substituted... also (and more importantly) when I try a sed commands script like this (in the cygwin shell):

> 1,/^END/{ /item_id/s/item_id=(\w*)/item_id=\U\1/g }

I also do not get the field uppercased.

I am completely flummoxed why this won't work...

I really don't care about the Mac thing )I just mentioned it for completeness) but I need my sed script to work 'cuz I am also doing a bunch of other substitutions (they all work) there.

For reference, here is the complete sedscript I am using:

```
1,/^END/{
    /item_id/s/item_id=\(\w*\)/item_id=\U\1/g
    /item_revision_id/s/item_revision_id=\(\w*\)/item_revision_id=\U\1/g
    /infodba/s/infodba,Project Administrator/mrslate,Project Administrator/g
    /fred/s/fred,Project Administrator/mrslate,Project Administrator/g
    /barney/s/barney,Project Administrator/mrslate,Project Administrator/g
    /dino/s/dino,Project Administrator/mrslate,Project Administrator/g
    /wilma/s/wilma,Project Administrator/mrslate,Project Administrator/g
    s/role_name="Ceramics"/role_name="DesignEngineer"/g
    s/role_name="Manager"/role_name="Management"/g
    s/role_name="Document Control Temp"/role_name="DataManager"/g
    s/role_name="Assembly Technician"/role_name="Viewer"/g
    s/role_name="Document Control"/role_name="DataManager"/g
    s/role_name="Analysis"/role_name="AnalysisEngineer"/g
    s/role_name="Manufacturing"/role_name="MfgEngineer"/g
    /barney/s/dba,barney,DBA/dba,mrslate,DBA/g
    /wilma/s/dba,wilma,DBA/dba,mrslate,DBA/g
    /fred/s/dba,fred,DBA/dba,mrslate,DBA/g
    /betty/s/Engineering,betty,Designer/Design.Bedrock,Migrator,DesignEngineer/g
}
```

Comment: Sorry not clear how you are calling `1,/^END/{ /item_id/s/item_id=(\w*)/item_id=\U\1/g }` .  However it gives to me `sed: -e expression #1, char 50: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: MacOS is Unix, not Linux. You're dealing with BSD sed, not GNU sed. Different programs with different abilities. Regardless, you should be using an XML parser to parse XML.

Comment: Dont get too hung up with the MacOs thing... that was simply informational.  Also, I appreciate the opinion about using xml parser but that is not the question I asked.

Comment: Maybe it's the question you should be asking...

Comment: u r funny.  I do miss the old Usenet.I understand if you don't know the answer.  When someone asks a specific question about Tool A, the answer is not "use Tool B".  XSLT is a useful tool, bit sometime slow.  when one has many thousands of files to process there are other ways to accomplish the task.  sed/awk/ed and other native Unix tools are sometimes selected for reasons not altogether apparent to the casual observer.

Answer (score 0):

After looking on http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4a
about `Extended Regular Expressions`
I noted the difference between `-e` and `-r`

So on cygwin

```
 $ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
Packaged by Cygwin (4.4-1)
..

$ echo is_configuration_item="N" is_vi="N" island_id="3281" item_id="AP2i4i_77" last_mod_date="2007-09-11T18:13:39Z" > prova.txt

$ sed -r  '1,/^END/{ /item_id/s/item_id=(\w*)/item_id=\U\1/g }' prova.txt
is_configuration_item=N is_vi=N island_id=3281 item_id=AP2I4I_77 last_mod_date=2007-09-11T18:13:39Z
```

while

```
$  sed  -e  '1,/^END/{ /item_id/s/item_id=(\w*)/item_id=\U\1/g }' prova.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 50: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: `-e` simply provides the command to be evaluated, and can be omitted if desired.

Comment: Understood, but this isn't a case of a "difference" between `-r` and `-e`, as they are completely unrelated. `-e` is always implied if it isn't explicitly provided. (Also, `-r` is deprecated, `-E` is the preferred argument to use for extended regex. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)